# Unix File updating using shell scripting

Tags: unix

I am having a requirement of updating a file with the latest variables or numbers considering a text file

**file1**

```
dan-2222
priya-23
rahul-288
rohit-233
```

**file2**

```
priya-22
rahul-288
rohit-230
```

I need the **file2** to be updated with the values of **file1** without any change in order using **Unix**.

I have used `diff` command and it is giving the different variables in both the files

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
for line in $(cat file1); do
    echo $line | IFS=- read var val
    sed -n "/$var/ s/.*/$var-$val/p" < file2; 
done > file2.new
```

file2.new should contain what you need.